# What code is able to read images included into program.jar app file; from anywhere?

Tags: java, image, load, relative-path, executable-jar

`image` is of type `BufferedImage`

```
public void loadImage(String fileImage) {

    URL imageurl = getClass().getResource(fileImage);

    File input = null;

    try {
        input = new File(imageurl.toURI());
        image = ImageIO.read(imageurl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown error has occurred!", "Unknown error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

This is how I invoke it in the program:

`loadImage("./Images/Cover.png");`

The images files are exactly located at:
*C:\Users\S\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\DictionaryShorten\src\dic\Images*

The **DictionaryShorten.java** file is located at:
*C:\Users\S\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\DictionaryShorten\src\dic*

The **images**  folder is included into the **DictionaryShorten.jar** after clicking the option **"clean and build"**; that means the images become part of the jar file.

The program is running OK from the NetBeanse IDE, but it throws exception when I run it from the **DictionaryShorten.jar** file!!!

How to modify `loadImage(String)` so that the **DictionaryShorten.jar** file can be run anywhere?

Comment: What folder is your .jar file in?

Comment: @LajosArpad - C:\Users\S\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\DictionaryShorten\dist

Answer (score 0):

The argument to Class.getResource is not a file name.  It is a relative URL, relative to the root of each classpath entry (such as a .jar file).

Remove the period (`.`) from your String argument.

Also, an entry in a .jar file is not an actual file, so `new File(imageurl.toURI())` will always fail.  You should remove that line of code.  (It appears you don't need it for anything anyway.)

It should be noted that exceptions are *very valuable.*  They tell you *what went wrong* and where.  You will find that problems are a lot easier to solve if you show the exception in your dialog:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown error has occurred:\n\n" + e,
    "Unknown error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Even better than that would be showing the full stack trace:

```
StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
JTextArea stackTraceField = new JTextArea(stackTrace.toString(), 12, 40);
stackTraceField.setEditable(false);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    new Object[] {
        "Unknown error has occurred.", new JScrollPane(stackTraceField)
    },
    "Unknown error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

The stack trace tells you exactly which line of code caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your .jar file, located in the dist (distribution) folder cannot find the Images folder which is being searched. If you would have an Images folder inside the dist folder, then it should work, however, if you create one, each time you clean the project, the folder would disappear. I believe you should create a separate folder, outside the project where you would have an Images folder and you could copy the .jar file into that after you build the project.